# Como ver características de sistema con PuTTY

Tags: linux, ssh

He accesado a un servidor virtual utilizando PuTTY y deseo saber las características del sistema como ser espacio en disco, procesadores, cores, RAM, etc. Sin embargo desconozco los comandos para ver esta información.

Estoy accediendo a un server Linux.

Comment: Esto no depende del PuTTY, depende del sistema operativo como tal y sus comandos...

Comment: En mi caso es un server de Linux. Entonces según tu comentario una vez conectado es como que este trabajando en la consola de Linux? @Jorius

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dando por hecho que estamos hablando de un servidor que maneja un sistema GNU/Linux, los comandos para ver las características de tu equipo son los siguientes:

- `free -m`: con este comando ves la memoria RAM en MB
- `lscpu`: con este comando ves la información del procesador
- `uname -a`: con esto puedes saber el sistema operativo, arquitectura y versión.
- `df -h`: con este comando puedes ver la memoria actual (disco duro) y cuánto se está usando (en porcentaje)
- `fdisk -l`: con este comando ves los discos que hay instalados en tu servidor, así como las particiones de cada disco.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar `lshw` que es una pequeña aplicación que te da toda la información que solicitas. Puede crear una salida en `json`, `xml` y `html`. Para mejores resultados, ejecútala como superusuario.

Por ejemplo, para ver la salida en `html`.

```
sudo lshw -html
```

Y eso es todo.

Comment: y si quiero que el html se genere como archivo en X directorio determinado???

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez puedes ejecutar el programa en el directorio destino o usar un `>`. Consulta el manual `man lshw`.